# Geth State heal in process explanation

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I had a synced geth node (syncmode default = snap).
After restarting the machine geth starts to sync again. Ten hours are passed but still syncing.
In the log file i see a lot of State heal in process.

Can someone explain in the following line

```
State heal in progress  accounts=79840@4.48MiB    slots=383,858@29.04MiB codes=1349@10.44MiB nodes=40,904,378@11.76GiB pending=97731
```

that the:
Accounts, slots, codes, nodes mean and which value indicating that the process is close to end.

P.S. I restarted the geth and accounts start for 0 again..

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here is some helpful information about how low IOPS performance can cause the state healing to go on forever: https://eth-docker.net/docs/Usage/ResourceUsage/#initial-sync-times

I measured mine to be adequate, but I also can't "parse" the log messages to understand how much healing is still left.

Answer (score 4):

I am certainly not an expert on this yet, but I would *assume* that the accounts figure will have to reach the total # of Ethereum accounts.

I have not been able to find a good chart on the growth of Eth accounts, except for [this chart](https://www.etherchain.org/charts/totalAccounts) that stops in Jan 2020 at 80+ million. But I would say: As long as your state heal runs faster than the growth of Eth accounts (roughly 100.000 per day, iirc), it should terminate *at some point*.

Hoping for somebody to correct me if I am wrong...

Also see [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/119267/geth-state-heal-in-progress-will-it-terminate) with the same explanation, which I posted separately because I didn't have enough reputation yet to answer protected questions.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) github -

- `accounts`: Number of accounts downloaded during the healing stage
- `slots`: Number of storage slots downloaded during the healing stage
- `codes`: Number of bytecodes downloaded
- `nodes`: Number of state trie nodes downloaded
- `pending`: Pending returns the number of state entries currently pending for download.

Can see most of these [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/1b58e42802eaa0f69295be95b675e8dfb99eeb4f/eth/protocols/snap/sync.go#L394).

```
    var (
        trienode = fmt.Sprintf("%v@%v", log.FormatLogfmtUint64(s.trienodeHealSynced), s.trienodeHealBytes.TerminalString())
        bytecode = fmt.Sprintf("%v@%v", log.FormatLogfmtUint64(s.bytecodeHealSynced), s.bytecodeHealBytes.TerminalString())
        accounts = fmt.Sprintf("%v@%v", log.FormatLogfmtUint64(s.accountHealed), s.accountHealedBytes.TerminalString())
        storage  = fmt.Sprintf("%v@%v", log.FormatLogfmtUint64(s.storageHealed), s.storageHealedBytes.TerminalString())
    )
    log.Info("State heal in progress", "accounts", accounts, "slots", storage,
        "codes", bytecode, "nodes", trienode, "pending", s.healer.scheduler.Pending())
```