# Geth state heal in progress - will it terminate?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107790/geth-state-heal-in-process-explanation), but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post my thoughts there.

I have been tracking my state heal progress for some time now, and I have a theory on whether it will terminate or not:

```
INFO [01-15|07:01:57.450] State heal in progress                   accounts=234,886@12.60MiB slots=177,637@12.90MiB codes=328@2.53MiB
 nodes=10,290,076@3.99GiB pending=120,372 
INFO [01-15|18:05:26.825] State heal in progress                   accounts=373,260@20.28MiB slots=322,952@23.47MiB codes=416@3.17MiB
 nodes=12,176,733@4.63GiB pending=111,606
INFO [01-15|18:23:34.964] State heal in progress                   accounts=373,983@20.32MiB slots=322,952@23.47MiB codes=416@3.17MiB
 nodes=12,204,854@4.64GiB pending=117,597 
INFO [01-16|11:05:37.114] State heal in progress                   accounts=583,590@31.54MiB slots=658,297@47.81MiB codes=520@4.01MiB
 nodes=14,941,295@5.49GiB pending=104,709
```

I am certainly not an expert on this yet, but I would *assume* that the accounts figure will have to reach the total # of Ethereum accounts.

I have not been able to find a good chart on the growth of Eth accounts, except for [this](https://www.etherchain.org/charts/totalAccounts) chart that stops in Jan 2020 at 80+ million. But I would say: As long as my state heal runs faster than the growth of Eth accounts (roughly 100.000 per day, iirc), it should terminate *at some point*. (In my case probably in months due to weak hardware, but that's not my point)

Am I getting this right?

Comment: i am also having the same problem as you, have you ever solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, but I am starting to doubt that StackExchange is the right place to get it resolved. Maybe I'll head over to https://www.reddit.com/r/ethstaker/ or another eth related subreddit. There's far to little visibility and traffic here.

Comment: I have the same issue, did it resolve?

Comment: No, I canceled it because my hardware was too weak, and based on my calculation (see above) it would not have finished.